# ServiceStack LoadSelect not properly <Into> references

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a case where I want to use `ServiceStack.OrmLite` `LoadSelect` to populate a POCO that is comprised of columns from multiple tables.

The basic background is that there are service requests (for a field tech to complete), and a separate assignment table.  For part of the application, I want to combine `ServiceRequest` and `ServiceRequestAssignment` into a single `ServiceRequestExtended` class.

Here are the POCOs:

```
public class ServiceRequest
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ... 

}

public class ServiceRequestAssignment
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(User))]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(ServiceRequest))]
    public int ServiceRequestId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public ServiceRequest ServiceRequest { get; set; }

    public double RelativeOrder { get; set; }

    [RowVersion]
    public ulong RowVersion { get; set; }
}

// Basically combines all fields of ServiceRequest & ServiceRequestAssignment
public class ServiceRequestExtended : ServiceRequest
{
    [References(typeof(User))]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public double RelativeOrder { get; set; }
    public ulong RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the (general) query being used:

```
var exp = Db.From<ServiceRequest>()
          .Join<ServiceRequestAssignment>()
          .Where<ServiceRequest, ServiceRequestAssignment>((q, r) => ...);

var results = Db.LoadSelect<ServiceRequestExtended, ServiceRequest>(exp);
```

When I do this, the query that LoadSelect generates to bring in the associated tables / POCOs is incorrect.  It references `ServiceRequestExtended` instead of the proper child table (in this case `ServiceRequestAssignment`) in the subselect.

Here's the SQL:

```
SELECT "Id", "UserName", "TechnicianNumber", "FirstName", "LastName", "PIN",     "Active", "Salt"
FROM "Users" WHERE "Id" 
IN (SELECT "ServiceRequestExtended"."UserId" 
    FROM "ServiceRequest" 
    INNER JOIN "ServiceRequestAssignment"
    ON ("ServiceRequest"."Id" = "ServiceRequestAssignment"."ServiceRequestId")
    WHERE ...)
```

So - what am I doing wrong?  Is there a bug in `LoadSelect<Into, From>`?

Comment: I've also tried the `BelongsTo` attribute on `ServiceRequestExtended.UserId` with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OrmLite Self References](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#self-references) can only be on **real** tables as OrmLite needs to query the existing reference field Ids to populate the POCO references.

Comment: I suppose it'd be easy enough to do a manual translation via "PopulateWith", or even more explicitly with a new ServiceRequestExtended(){ ... } after the data is loaded.